# A double-log plot from fitted data to Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD)

Tags: r, data-fitting, power-law

I'd to like to fit GPD to a dataset and then plot a double-log chart showing all the using data points with a trend line showing asymptotic GPD.
I have the code to fit my data using VGAM package but don't know how to get the desired plot. The code is:

```
library("VGAM")
gdata <- data.frame(V1 = rexp(n = 3000, rate = 2))
fit <- vglm(V1 ~ 1, gpd(), data = gdata, trace = TRUE)
Coef(fit)
```

I want to get a diagram similar to this explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5B63.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Build a table and cumsum it, Then reverse that result. (I think). But with no data to work with I'm not inclined to build an example so I can test my theory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have modified the code to work with real data.